# How to add a feed back button to knowledge article

Tags: knowledge

Is it possible to add a feedback button Yes/No . Did this article answered your question in the public knowledge articles ?

How to edit the page of knowledge articles in force.com site.

When the public users read the article they should click yes/no. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, is possible if you create a visualforce page for displaying the articles, then you could store the result of that action on a 'feedback' object.

To add a change the 'template' behind an article, go to the article type you wish to modify and select the visualforce page you have created (see Screenshot).

[image: Assign VF page to the Public Knowledge Base channel]

To be able to select the page, the page needs to use the current article type as standard controller.

Comment: Thanks Pepefloyd for reply. Currently we are displaying knowledge articles inside force.com site. As soon as we click on the link it is opening that article in default force.com site template. So where we can design our custom template page to open articles and add feedback buttons in that VF page.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Please explain how did you achieved this. We are also facing the same issue. It would be helpful to us. Thanks,